# AS3 Array TileMap Checking?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am creating a Indie City Building Game and I am trying to code a system to check if a Water Supply has been constructed within 4X4  of the set tile.

```
 var blankMap: Array = [{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                       {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
                       {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
                       {0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2}, 
                       {0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
                       {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0}, 
                       {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}];

public function checkWater(mY, mX): void {
        // LEFT
        if (blankMap[mY][mX - 1] == 8) {
            trace("resource found left");
        }
        if (blankMap[mY][mX - 2] == 8) {
            trace("resource found left");
        }
        if (blankMap[mY][mX - 3] == 8) {
            trace("resource found left");
        }
        if (blankMap[mY][mX - 4] == 8) {
            trace("resource found left");
        }
}

// RIGHT
if (blankMap[mY][mX + 1] == 8) {
            trace("resource found right");
        }
        if (blankMap[mY][mX + 2] == 8) {
            trace("resource found right");
        }
        if (blankMap[mY][mX + 3] == 8) {
            trace("resource found right");
        }
        if (blankMap[mY][mX + 4] == 8) {
            trace("resource found right");
        }
```

This system works, but only for east, south, west and north. Is there an easier way to do this? It will only check to see if the tiles 1, 2, 3 and 4 spaces away contain a water supply.... Which is the number 8 on the tile map. mY and mX are the position of the tile that was clicked.

Any advice would be brilliant. I basically need to be able to check the tile area/tile map (a 4X4 maximum distance) for the NUMBER 8 instead of 0 which would mean the tile is grass.  It sounds so easy and I am sure it is, I just can't get my head around this math. Thank you.

Comment: For loops, while loops, recursive functions would all work. [documentation for-loops](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3_Flex/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fcf.html)

Comment: And just as a tip, you should check wether or not you go out of bounds with the manipulated coordinates in your function. In your example code you will always run into errors when you try to check for north or south, given that your map has only a height of 7, but you travel a total of 8 (+1 for starting coordinate) tiles.

Answer (score 0):

Your blankMap looks invlid - it should be an array of arrays? Like

```
private var blankMap:Array = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0] ...
```

As DodgerThud has already mentioned you also need to check if the coordinates are within your map or you will run into an index out of bounds exception. I would do a general method so you can check if any resource is within a given reach, otherwise you'd need to write own functions for everything:

```
// check if there is a water supply within 3 tiles starting at x = 3, y = 1
var waterSupplyExists:Boolean = checkForResourceWithinReach(3, 1, 8, 3);

// startX is the x coordinate of your tile that was clicked
// startY is the y coordinate of your tile that was clicked
// resource is th eresource to look for (8 = water supply)
// reach is the distance to look for. 3 would mean we look 3 tiles away around your start tile (7x7 square) 
public function checkForResourceWithinReach(startX:int, startY:int, resource:int, reach:int):Boolean
{
    for (var x:int = startX - reach; x < startX + reach + 1; x++)
    {
        for (var y:int = startY - reach; y < startY + reach + 1; y++)
        {
            // check if this coordinate exists and if it has the resource we are looking for
            if (isWithinMap(x, y) && blankMap[y][x] == resource)
            {
                // found the resource
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    // nothing found
    return false;
}

// check if a x, y coordinate is within the bounds of the map arrays
private function isWithinMap(x:int, y:int):Boolean
{
    return x > 0 && y > 0 && x < blankMap[0].length && y < blankMap.length;
}
```